# js segment function no longer working

Tags: javascript, css

All of a sudden I have unintentionally been causing a piece of code to no longer work. I am using the below in order to show and simultaneously hide content within the same website file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(){
            $('section').hide();
            $($(this).attr('data-url')).show();
            var $this = $(this),
            $ul = $this.parents('ul');
            $ul.find('a').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
        }); 
    </script>
```

Below is the html-code that is being displayed and hidden:

```
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="#content1">Content1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-url="#content2">Content2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="#content3">Content3</a></li>
    </ul>

        <section id="content1">
            Some content 1
        </section>

        <section id="content2">
            Some content 2
        </section>

        <section id="content3">
            Some content 3
        </section>
```

Below is the CSS code:

```
section {
    display: none;
}

section:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}

ul.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    color: #349cf0;
}

ul.tabs li a.active {
    color: #349cf0;
}
```

I have no idea why this suddenly stopped working. Now I have not included all the stuff thats on the website. Can anyone of you perhaps explain to me what could possibly be interfering with the code? Maybe I accidentally changed something in the js. I received the code from someone else and am not able to spot any errors myself. I would very much appreciate if anyone here will be able to spot any errors!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the browsers' console log to see if any errors are generated. Open web page and press F12.

Comment: You got something outside this code that's causing the problem. Here's  JS Bin of your code, seems to be working: https://jsbin.com/tepigitiqu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I went backed to what I had last been working on and found the error. I could have been circling around that js. code for hours - so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/L0Lnav2t/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(){
            $('section').hide();
            $($(this).attr('data-url')).show();
            var $this = $(this),
            $ul = $this.parents('ul');
            $ul.find('a').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
        }); 
    </script>
```

I assume your code causes another error before the onclick listener is initialized, rendering it dysfunctional.

On its own it seems to be fine though